# Passing Two Parameters Through URL in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm having difficulty passing parameters to a URL in Django.

I am attempting to pass two parameters from calander.html -> succ.html. The URL looks like this:
[Click for Image of URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ICCM.png)

In that image I want to pass 11:00am as the Start Time and 12:00pm as the end Time.

My urls.py file contains:

```
path('calender', views.calender, name='calender'),
....
....
path('succ', views.succ, name='succ'),
```

My views.py file contatins:

```
def calender(request):
return render(request, 'calender.html')

def succ(request):
return render(request, 'succ.html')
```

I attempted to add parameters to the views.py file and then add a new path in urls.py after watching several videos and I was never able to find a solution since I am passing two parameters (StartTime and EndTime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Colons `:` are invalid for urls, use underscores `_` instead and do a `start = start.replace('_', ':')` in the view if you really need the colon

I'm not sure if that was your only issue you were running into, but here's two broken down ways you can pass parameters to a view.
They both essentially do the same thing

#### 1 Using Django URLs

```py
## Urls
# Notes:
#   both point at the same view (See next section)
#   <slug> means it's a string

path('calender', views.calender, name='calender'),

path('calender/<slug:StartDate>/<slug:EndDate>', views.calender, name='calender'),
# Example: calendar/11_00am/12_00pm
```

```py
## Views (Note: Setting them as None allows you two have 2 URL paths pointing to a single view)
def calender(request, StartDate=None, EndDate=None):
  if StartDate and EndDate:
    # do things
    #   maybe render a different template or maybe just pass to render

    # EndDate = EndDate.replace('_', ':') # 12:00pm format

return render(request, 'calender.html')
```

#### 2 Using GET parameters

```py
## Urls
# Notes:
#   Single Path, Will pass parameters with GET
#   Generally you have to manually attach GETs to a URL (Either in Template Logic <a> , or Javascript) 

path('calender', views.calender, name='calender'),
# Example: calendar?StartDate=11_00am&EndDate=12_00pm
```

```py
## Views
def calender(request):
  # Note: Using GET.get() will return None if it's not there
  #   which is probably better than GET[] which would crash if it's not there
  StartDate = request.GET.get('StartDate')
  EndDate = request.GET.get('EndDate')
  if StartDate and EndDate:
    # do things
    #   maybe render a different template or maybe just pass to render

    # EndDate = EndDate.replace('_', ':') # 12:00pm format

return render(request, 'calender.html')
```

---

#### edit

And this is just very general. Sorry I used Calendar as the examples instead of succ.html, was my bad. Naturally just copy some of that into succ and it’ll work the same. Hope you find this useful! :-)

Comment: First off, I'm not that great at Django yet. However, are you passing parameters in for the calendar? Because it's the succ.html I need to pass my query parameters for. For this, would I edit your post to succ.html instead of calendar?

Comment: @DustinMckinney yes yes! My bad! I actually wrote an edit apologizing while you were probably reading it. I can redo it if you have troubles.

Comment: Thanks fo helping! I am still getting this after adding what you have suggested. https://imgur.com/0IxHK4C

Comment: You went **#1** route, so you don’t use &’s- so just replace that & with another slash. Should look like this: succ/11_00am/12_00pm

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I changed the &'s to /'s and I am still getting this error :(
Here are screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/vIdZEXe

Comment: Remove the “start=“ and the “end=“ the final url should just be: “succ/7pm/8pm”